# How to transform SSE assembly code to AVX1/2 assembly code?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, avx2

I'm trying to convert a function from AVX to AVX2, in NASM or MASM (Intel syntax). In particular:

```
vmovapd xmm0, XMMWORD PTR [rax]
```

works like a charm.

```
vmovapd ymm0, YMMWORD PTR [rax]
```

throws an exception:

> Exception levée à 0x00007FF73F7818EC dans x64asm.exe : 0xC0000005 :
>   Violation d'accès lors de la lecture de l'emplacement
>   0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF.

I don't understand what I did wrong.

Comment: Your first version is legacy SSE, not AVX1.  And AVX1 includes packed-double. 
 Anyway, presumably your pointer is only 16-byte aligned, not 32.  You could use [`vmovupd`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/movupd), or increase the alignment of whatever you're pointing to.  Impossible to say more without more context.  My French is rusty, but if `0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF` is the address in RAX you're trying to load from, then the real bug was earlier and you've already corrupted your pointer.

Comment: `vmovapd xmm0, [rax]` and `vmovapd ymm0, [rax]` are both AVX1 instructions: AVX1 added 256-bit versions of SIMD FP instructions (and VEX encoding for all legacy SSE instructions where memory operands can be misaligned, except for alignment-required loads/stores like `vmovapd/ps`); AVX2 added 256-bit versions of integer SIMD instructions as well, and some lane-crossing shuffles.  What you're really asking is how to widen your vectors to 256-bit.  See also https://stackoverflow.com/tags/avx/info and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/avx2/info

Answer (score 0):

It's OK, it was due to misaligned arrays.

Thank you for your time and your explanation.